# Angular Format date, ionic

Tags: angularjs, html, date, time, ionic-framework

Im using ionicframework to build hybrid app with angular.
im having a form with two input box : date and time. The value of date input is saved in the database as: 
`Tue Mar 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT 0300 (AST)` i get this type of data when running the form on my android device, but i want to save the date as simple like: `24-04-2015`

What i tried

**form.html**

```
<form>
<input ng-model="app.date" class="positive" type="date">
<input ng-model="app.time" class="positive" type="time">
<button ng-click="makeApp(app)">send</button>
</form>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.makeApp = function (app) {
$http.post("http://www.foo.com/senddata.php?date="+app.date+"&time="+app.time)
.success(function(data){   
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Angular's date filter:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.makeApp = function (app) {

        var appDate = $filter('date')(app.date, "dd/MM/yyyy");
        $http.post("http://www.foo.com/senddata.php?date="+appDate+"&time="+app.time)
            .success(function(data){   
                // success
            });
    }
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date